# What is the best way to store axis names for a list of ggplots?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I create a large dataframe (>100 columns)

```
s <- data.frame(x1, x2,....,x100)
var_list <- names(s)
```

And then I manually create another list of 100 names for corresponding y-axes:

```
y_names <- c("Time", "hr", "W m-2"..... 100 items)
```

In the end, I loop through the list to create a single PDF of 100 plots:

```
plot_list = list()
for (i in 2:length(var_list)) {
  p = ggplot(s, aes_string(x = x1, y = var_list[i])) +
    geom_line()+
    ylab(y_names[i])+
    ggtitle(paste(var_list[i]))
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

 # create pdf where each page is a separate plot. ,
pdf("figures.pdf",  width=7, height=1.5)
for (i in 2:length(var_list)) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

Obviously, this is a problem, as I can never be sure whether I am giving the right y-axis to the right plot, other than by looking at the final plot. And if I have to make changes to the order, that's a whole different mess.

How can I set names in a better way? Maybe in the dataframe itself where I can be sure of the order?

Comment: Are there specific `var_list` values that always match with specific `y_names`?  For example, is there a column name like `wm` that you always want translated to `W m-2` in the plot? If so you can create a look-up table and then use a join to match the appropriate `y-axis` label to each column name, without having to know the order. It will be easier to help you if you provide a small data sample and the matching y-axis labels that go with the column names.

Comment: `Var_list` is just the name of the columns. And every column is associated with a unique `y_names`. Some may not have any y_names as they maybe fractions without units.  I'll try to provide some data as they are big. But if you could elaborate with any example data, that would be  great too!

Comment: I've added an answer. As it turned out, a join wasn't necessary. I just used the `match` function to get the `y_lab` corresponding to the y column used for each plot.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks a lot! It helps a lot. But it still doesn't help me set the unit next to the variable in the code, which makes the code unwieldy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookup table along with the `match` function. This ensures that the desired y-axis label is always used for a given data column. Here's an example:

Let's create a lookup table with the y-labels we want to use for all possible column names. In `lookup`, `var_names` are the possible column names of the data frame `s`. `y_lab` are the corresponding y-axis labels we want to use in the plot.

```
lookup = data.frame(var_names=c("wm","hr","time","grp", 'cm'), 
                    y_lab=c("W m-2", "Hour", "Time", "Group","Centimeters"))
```

> ```
>   var_names       y_lab
> 1        wm       W m-2
> 2        hr        Hour
> 3      time        Time
> 4       grp       Group
> 5        cm Centimeters
> ```

Now, when you plot the data, use `match` to identify the correct `lookup$y_lab` for the given y column in the plot. In the example below, I've altered your code sample to directly use the data frame column names as the loop variable. Note the use of the `match` function to get the correct `y_lab` for the current value of `yvar`.

```
for (yvar in names(s)[-1]) {
  p = ggplot(s, aes_string(x = "x1", y = yvar)) +
    geom_line() +
    ylab(lookup$y_lab[match(yvar, lookup$var_names)]) +
    ggtitle(yvar)
  plot_list[[yvar]] = p
}
```

Another option would be to create a single faceted plot of all the y values. That would go something like this:

```
library(tidyr)

names(s)[-1] = lookup$y_lab[match(names(s)[-1], lookup$var_names)]

ggplot(gather(s, key, value, -x1), aes(x = x1, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ key)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: TBH, it still doesn't fix the issue quite as we are not assigning the `units` next to the `variable` names in the `lookup`. So, when I have hundreds of variables, it is tough to make changes without looking up the table in RStudio in tabular format. I am leaving the question up to see if I can find a solution for that. But thanks!

Comment: I wonder if there is a way construct a dataframe `row-wise` rather than `column-wise`? That would solve the problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example data frame and desired output? That would make it easier for me to understand what you're trying to do.